# Which $F$ & $G$ satisfy $\int_0^{\pi}F(\sin (x))\cos (x)\, dx=0$ &$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin (x)\,G(\cos (x))\,dx=0$?

Tags: integration, trigonometry

Which functions $F$ & $G$ satisfy:- $\int_0^{\pi}F(\sin (x))\cos(x)\,dx=0$ and $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\sin(x)\,G(\cos(x))\,dx=0?$

---

Equivalent relationships are given in [The Universal Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://science.sciencemag.org/content/146/3642/390.2)(1976 edition) page 597.  But the specifics of the functions $F$ and $G$ are not given.

The rules DO NOT apply for various functions such as:- 
$F(\sin(x))= x\,{\sin(x)}$, $F(\sin(x))=\exp(x)\,{\sin(x)}$ , $F(\sin(x))=\frac{\text{d}(\sin (x))}{\text{d} x}{\cos(x)}.$

It seems to me that the rules DO apply only for "pure" functions of $\sin (x)$ (for $F$) and $\cos (x)$ (for $G$) respectively.

"Pure" in this sense means, for example, that the following pattern is valid:- $F(\sin(x)) = m\sin^n(x)$ for real numbers: $m,n$.

Whereas functions $F(\sin(x))$ which contain some (any?) functions of $x$ other than $\sin(x)$ may be designated "Impure".  Also included in the impure category would be differentials and integrals of $\sin(x)$ with respect to $x$.

---

**Question**

Is there a succinct way of identifying the two domains "pure" and "impure".?

---

**Update 1**

The question arose from overlooking the strict mathematical definition of "function of" . The cited Universal Encyclopedia of Mathematics, p227-228 presents: "In the strict mathematical interpretation $y$ is called a function of $x$ if, corresponding to each permissible value of $x$, a ### value of $y$ can be calculated or observed". Perhaps the words "single, definite" should be inserted at the position marked by ###?

According to this definition, $|x|$ is a function of $x^2$ but $x$ is not a function of $x^2$.

I also learned that $F(x) = \int f(x) \space\text{d}x"$ does not mean that $F(x)$ is a function of $f(x)$ in the strict, mathematical sense. Likewise for functions related by differentiation.

---

**Update 2**

The above hypotheiszed categories:- "pure functions" and "impure functions" are represented by the formal categories:- "injective functions" and "non-injective functions" as described here:- [injective functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

For the rules in the title to be true the functions $F$ and $G$ must be injective functions.  For example the function $$y_1 = F_1(x) =\arcsin(\sin(x))$$ is not injective because a single value of $\sin(x)$ maps to multiple values of $y_1$. An injective function can be derived by setting an appropriately restricted range of $x$, as in the function $$y_2 = F_2(x) =\arcsin(\sin(x)) \space{} (-\pi/2 <= x <= \pi/2).$$

Comment: Why do you think it does not work for $F(\sin x)=\sqrt{1-\sin^2 x}=\lvert\cos x\rvert$ for example?

Comment: $\exp x\sin x$ isn't a function of $\sin x$, because e.g. $\exp\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2}\ne\exp\frac{5\pi}{2}\sin\frac{5\pi}{2}$.

Comment: What about $F=0$?

Comment: @David can you expand/clarify please?

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is $[\widetilde{F}(\sin x)]_0^\pi=0$ for your favourite antiderivative $\widetilde{F}$ of $F$, so any continuous $F$ integrable on $[0,\,1]$ will work. Similarly, your second problem is $[\widetilde{G}(\cos x)]_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}=0$ for an antiderivative $\widetilde{G}$ of $G$, so you just need $G$ to be continuous and integrable on $[0,\,1]$.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something about the mathematical definition of function.  If (in the Encyclopedia context) $F_a(\sin(x))=2*sin(x)$ IS a valid function of $(\sin(x))$ but $F_b(\sin(x))=x*sin(x)$ IS NOT valid then I feel the need for some term or words to define the difference.

Comment: I think integrability of $F$ and $G$ is not enough, we would need them to be continuous. Or at least, in general, if $g$ is continuous and $f$ is Riemann-integrable then $f \circ g$ is not necessarily Riemann-integrable.

Comment: @Botond $x*\sin(x)$ is integrable across $0,\pi$ but is not valid in the Encyclopedia context.

Comment: @steveOw Knowing $\sin x$ doesn't in general mean you know $x\sin x$, so $x\sin x$ isn't a function of $\sin x$, just as $x^3$ isn't a function of $x^2$.

Comment: @steveOw If we let $f(x)=x\sin^{-1}(x)$, then $f(\sin(x))=\sin(x)\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$. But we will have a little problem with $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))$. We have that $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x))=x$ on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, but outside that it's not the identity function. See the plot on wolfram alpha, for example: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+arcsin(sin(x))

Comment: @Botond Good point; I am using the FTC, so continuity is important. I've fixed my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Constructing a counter-example is not so easy, but it's possible, check this question, for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20045/about-the-riemann-integrability-of-composite-functions

Comment: @Botond good points. It seems to be partly an issue of semantics e.g. does $F(\sin(x))$ mean (a) a function of $\sin(x)$ alone or (b) a function in which $\sin(x)$ is a factor? The formal math definition seems to point to (a).  But - in the Encyclopedia context - valid functions of $F(\sin(x))$ also may include multipliers and powers e.g. $F(\sin(x) )= 2*\sin^3(x)$...I think that words (or a relevant term if available) are required in the Encyclopedia to clarify what is or is not a valid form of $F(\sin(x))$.

Comment: @steveOw I think this is about terminology only.  I'd say that $f(\sin(x))$ is a function of $\sin(x)$ for any $f$ (of couse, if the composition is well-defined).

Comment: @Botond, Yes, the right Terminology is what I seek. Possibly: "$F(\sin(x))$ is a function containing $\sin(x)$ but excluding any other function of $x$ or integrals or derivatives of $\sin(x)$".

Comment: @JG  I had been missing the distinction between:-  (PURE) "a function of $\sin(x)$ and no other functions of $x$" and (IMPURE) "a function of $\sin(x)$ which might include other functions of $x$". The point about $x$ not being unambiguosly obtainable (via $\arcsin(\sin(x))$) from the value of $\sin(x)$ over the range $0,\pi$ is key here.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we have:
$$\int_0^\pi F(\sin x)\cos (x)dx=0$$
if we let $u=\sin(x)$ then $dx=\frac{du}{\cos(x)}$ and the integral can also be split into:
$$\int_0^\pi=\int_0^{\pi/2}+\int_{\pi/2}^\pi$$
so the problem can be simplified as follows:
$$\int_0^1F(u)du+\int_1^0F(u)du=0$$
since the integral on the right is just the negative of the integral on the left, this is true for all $F(u)$ which are continuous and integratable for $u\in[0,1]$.

---

Secondly, we have:
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}G(\cos x)\sin(x)dx=0$$ 
using the same method as above you can prove once again that this is true for any $G(u)$ for $u\in[0,1]$

Comment: What does this imply about the meaning (in the given Encyclopedia context) of $F(a)$ or $G(a)$? E.g. does $F(a)$ mean that $F$ is a function of $1a^1$ and of $1a^1$ only? presumably no, because $3a^2$ is allowed. But it does exclude $x*(\sin (x))$

Comment: Any continuous function you can probably think of will work

Comment: I'm trying to find wording that indicates that $F_1(\sin(x)) = 3*\sin(x)$ is an acceptable function of $\sin(x)$ while $F_2(\sin(x)) = x*\sin(x)$ is not an acceptable function of $\sin(x)$.  Maybe I dont understand the basic meaning of "function"?

Comment: there are no limitations on it, do you have proof that $F_2(\sin x)=x\sin(x)$ does not work?

Comment: [$\int_0^{\pi}(x*\sin x)*\cos x\, \text{d}x=-\pi/4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x*sin(x)+*+cos+x+dx+between+0+and+pi)

Answer (score 1):

It's not about pure vs impure... the function $x\sin x$ is simply not function of $\sin x$, and similarly for your other examples. Take $x = {2\pi \over 3}$ and $x = {\pi \over 3}$ for example. They both have $\sin x = {\sqrt{3} \over 2}$ but different values of $x\sin x$.

The function $\sin x\,G(\cos x)$ is an odd function, so basically in any situation where $\int_{-{\pi \over 2}}^{\pi \over 2}\sin x\,G(\cos x)\,dx$ is defined this integral will be zero. This can be seen for example by changing variables from $x$ to $-x$; when one does this the integral is simply multiplied by $-1$. The only number equal to its negative is zero, so the integral is zero.

The same idea works for the first integral, since the integrand $I(x) = F(\sin x) \cos x$ satisfies $I(\pi - x) = -I(x)$ and therefore the change of variables from $x$ to $\pi - x$ also multiplies the integral by $-1$. Hence the first integral is also zero.

Comment: More generally, is the statement "A: $x\sin x$ is NOT a function of $\sin x$" true because $x$ can NOT be derived with certainty from the value of $\sin x$ alone"? And is it accordingly that "B: $\cos^2$ x IS a function of $\sin x$ " is true because $\cos^2 x$  CAN be derived with certainty from the value of $\sin x$ alone?

Comment: steveOw Yes, that is the usual definition of function.

Comment: Yet entities such as $\arcsin, \arctan, \arccos$ are commonly called functions (without qualification) despite the fact that they are not one-to-one. And I see that the category of ["injective functions"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) has been introduced, which helps to clarify the situation.

Comment: For functions like $\arcsin$ and so on, they restrict the domain so that the functions can be made well defined and continuous. So for example $\arcsin$ is defined on $[-1,1]$ and its range is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.

Comment: The point I am focussed on (now that I have learned the appropriate term "injective") is the fact there is a perspective (recognized by some people) which makes a distinction between "injective functions" and "non-injective functions" with the latter presumably being a non-empty set.  Thus, IMO, the optimum answer to my original question would be something like:- "functions F and G must be injective".